# JOIN returns empty set

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to show the names and IDs of all artists who have not recorded titles but do have web addresses listed in my database.

This invovles two tables:

```
Artists
-------
ArtistID, ArtistName, City, Region, WebAddress

Titles
------
TitleID, ArtistID, Title, StudioID, Genre
```

My query is as follows:

```
 select ar.*
 from artists ar
 inner join titles t
 on ar.artistid = t.artistid
 where ar.webaddress != NULL;
```

which returns an empty set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MySql, null is not a value, so `where ar.webaddress != NULL;` will not work.  There is special syntax for checking nulls, `is null` and `is not null` for example.  Also, the inner join will only give you artists that have titles.  To get artists without titles, try outer join and check for null in the joined table

i.e.

```
 select ar.*
 from artists ar
 left join titles t
 on ar.artistid = t.artistid
 where ar.webaddress Is not NULL
 and t.ArtistID is null;
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that null is not a value so you cant mention it with equal or not equal symbol: 
Try this:

```
select *
from artists
where ar.webaddress Is not NULL
and artistid not in(select distinct artistid in titles)
```

Comment: Won't this still find all artists that do have a recorded title though?

Comment: This returns all those are not null.

Comment: It appears, by the question, cryptomath is looking for artists that don't have titles, i.e. don't exist in the Titles table

Comment: sql server treats NULL as unknown value so checking against NULL with operators like != or <> can return unexpected results. therefore we use IS NULL or IS NOT NULL. Since NULL is treated as unknown value cant really compare an unknown value to anything :)

Comment: After your edit it does work now. However the distinct would only make things slower. It can (should?) be safely removed.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ar.*
FROM Artists a INNER JOIN Titles T
ON A.ArtistID = T..ArtistID
WHERE a.WebAddress IS NOT NULL 
AND T.Title IS NULL
```

This will return records where there is a `Webaddress` but `no title` for a person